# Laravel 4 View Nesting Main Layout Subviews Content and Sidebar

Tags: laravel-4

This is my first post so please be gentle with me.

I have set my master layout to call "main"

```
  <div class="row">
      {{$main}}    
  </div>
```

and I have a view called home.blade

```
     <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="content">
        {{$content}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <aside class="sidebar">
        {{$sidebar}}
      </aside>
    </div>
```

and in my controller I have:-

```
    $this->layout->main = View::make('home')->nest('content', 'property.viewmany', compact('properties'));
```

This works for the content variable, but at this point I'm stumped at how to get the sidebar variable to work. Is there a way to nest the two variables into the home.blade from the controller?

I've attempt various, albeit, shots in the dark, but I always get either content not defined or sidebar not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a first variable in the first view like this:

```
$this->layout->main = View::make('home', compact('sidebar'))->nest('content',  'property.viewmany', compact('properties'));
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting so late in the day, your answer provided the right thinking for me to move forwards.